# drogon c++ doesn't generate sql for primary key insertion

Tags: c++

i am using sqlite, drogon version 1.7.1

I have table, code for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "storage_device_info" (
    "device_id" INTEGER,
    "volume_name"   TEXT,
    "volume_description"    TEXT,
    "volume_drive_letter"   TEXT,
    "volume_size"   INTEGER,
    "volume_file_system"    TEXT,
    "storage_name"  TEXT,
    "storage_description"   TEXT,
    "storage_capacity"  INTEGER,
    "storage_serial"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("device_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("device_id") REFERENCES "device"("id")
);
```

I generated model "StorageDeviceInfo" for this table with drogon CLI tool.

I create an object of this model, setting device_id to proper device id.

Then try to insert through `Mapper\<StorageDeviceInfo\>.insert`

And i am getting "Foreign key constraint failed error"

on generated model, the function for generating SQL insertion doesn't have device_id parameter, and looks like this:

```
std::string sqlForInserting(bool &needSelection) const
    {
        std::string sql="insert into " + tableName + " (";
        size_t parametersCount = 0;
        needSelection = false;
        if(dirtyFlag_[1])
        {
            sql += "volume_name,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[2])
        {
            sql += "volume_description,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[3])
        {
            sql += "volume_drive_letter,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[4])
        {
            sql += "volume_size,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[5])
        {
            sql += "volume_file_system,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[6])
        {
            sql += "storage_name,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[7])
        {
            sql += "storage_description,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[8])
        {
            sql += "storage_capacity,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(dirtyFlag_[9])
        {
            sql += "storage_serial,";
            ++parametersCount;
        }
        if(parametersCount > 0)
        {
            sql[sql.length()-1]=')';
            sql += " values (";
        }
        else
            sql += ") values (";
        
        if(dirtyFlag_[1])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[2])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[3])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[4])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[5])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[6])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[7])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[8])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(dirtyFlag_[9])
        {
            sql.append("?,");

        } 
        if(parametersCount > 0)
        {
            sql.resize(sql.length() - 1);
        }
        sql.append(1, ')');
        LOG_TRACE << sql;
        return sql;   
    }
```

Is this bug? Or I am inserting it wrong?
What can I do to insert my model?